# draw a line as if I wanted to draw house plan

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm new to PIXI.js, and I try to build a line in a specific way :

When I click on the mouse, and while the left click is pressed, I want to draw a line from where I click to the area where I released the left click.

The best I achieved is almost what I want, but I would like to get rid of all the "intermediate" lines that appear.

Here's what I did (don't look at the quality :p) :

```
let app = new PIXI.Application(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

app.stage.interactive = true;

const background = new PIXI.Graphics();
background.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
background.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFFFF);
background.drawRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
background.interactive = true;
app.stage.addChild(background);

let lines = [];

let initialMoveTo;

background.on("mousedown", (event) => {
    background.isCreatingLine = true;

    let mouseX = event.data.global.x;
    let mouseY = event.data.global.y;

    initialMoveTo = [mouseX, mouseY];

    let line = new PIXI.Graphics();
    line.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
    line.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);

    lines = [line].concat(lines);

    app.stage.addChild(line);
});

background.on("mousemove", (event) => {
    if (background.isCreatingLine) {
        let mouseX = event.data.global.x;
        let mouseY = event.data.global.y;

        lines[0].moveTo(initialMoveTo[0], initialMoveTo[1]);
        lines[0].lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
});

background.on("mouseup", (event) => {
    background.isCreatingLine = false;
});


document.body.appendChild(app.view);
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/busmagique/pen/paXZaV)

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code and it seems to work the way you would like.

```
background.on("mousemove", (event) => {
    if (background.isCreatingLine) {
        let mouseX = event.data.global.x;
        let mouseY = event.data.global.y;
        lines[0].clear();
        lines[0].lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        lines[0].moveTo(initialMoveTo[0], initialMoveTo[1]);
        lines[0].lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
});
```

Each time the mouse moves clear the current line stored in lines[0] then reapply the style and the new position.

Comment: Can you give some details about why `.clear()` was necessary ?

Comment: In your code you create a new Graphics object for each line. However a Graphics object can store many lines and display them on screen. So in this instance it stores all the lines from mousedown to mouseup. Clear simply removes all the previous lines so only the most recent is displayed.